# volatile in spring controller not working

Tags: java, spring, controller, volatile

here is the code segment

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

class VolatileTest{
    private static boolean stop = false;
    public void go() throws Exception{

        new Thread(()->{
            System.out.println("thread started in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            int counter = 0;
            while (!stop){
                counter++;
            };

            // #1
            System.out.println("stopped at i=" + counter + " in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }).start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        stop = true;
    }
}

@RestController
public class MyVolatileController {

    @GetMapping("/volatile/test")
    public String test(){
        new Thread(()->{
            try{
                new VolatileTest().go();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }).start();

        return "volatile";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new Thread(()->{
            try{
                new VolatileTest().go();
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }).start();
    }

}
```

the expected behavior: when called, the program will never reach #1, since stop is not volatile, and the change made by other thread will not been seen immediately by the current thread.

**Question**: when it is started in `public void static main` of the class, it behaves as expected, however, when started inside a spring `controller method`, it does reach #1. why is that happening ?

Comment: `new VolatileTest().go();` indicates that this is not a spring bean which is used. Please share the code that is used in spring.

Comment: `stop` is static and shared, so if you run `go` multiple times, subsequent runs will (likely) immediately see `stop` set to true.